# zc buildout version conflict. django 1.3 but requires 1.4.2 for django-debug-toolbar

Tags: python, django, makefile, buildout, django-debug-toolbar

I'm trying to do a buildout. Project is ran on django 1.3. When I try to do buildout I get this error:

```
Installing django.
While:
  Installing django.
Error: There is a version conflict.
We already have: Django 1.3
but django-debug-toolbar 1.2.1 requires 'django>=1.4.2'.
make: *** [bin/django] Error 1
```

What are my options here?

My `buildout.cfg`:

```
[buildout]
parts =
    apacheconf
    production.py
    my.cnf
    mkdir
    django
#   scribd-patch
    jquery-ui
    tinymce

download-cache = cache

eggs =
    PIL
    South
    django
    django-annoying
    django-sugar
    python-scribd
    django-mptt
    django-filebrowser-no-grappelli
    django-webtopay
    django-pagination
    django-registration
    feincms
    mock
    simplejson
    djangorestframework
    djangorestframework-csv
    markdown

extra-paths = project


allowed-eggs-from-site-packages =
    PIL
    setuptools
    distribute

extensions = mr.developer
sources = sources
sources-dir = parts
auto-checkout = *

versions = versions

servername = www.myproject.com
serveradmin = admin@myproject.com

[sources]
# my.package = svn http://example.com/svn/my.package/trunk
# some.other.package = git git://example.com/git/some.other.package.git
# bzr.package = bzr bzr+ssh://bazaar.launchpad.net/~user/project/branch/
python-scribd = svn http://python-scribd.googlecode.com/svn/trunk
django-annoying = hg https://bitbucket.org/sirex/django-annoying
django-sugar = git git://github.com/montylounge/django-sugar.git
django-filebrowser-no-grappelli = git git://github.com/wardi/django-filebrowser-no-grappelli.git
django-webtopay = git git://github.com/Motiejus/django-webtopay.git

[versions]
South = 0.7.3
django = 1.3
django-mptt = 0.4.2
django-pagination = 1.0.7
django-registration = 0.8
feincms = 1.4.2
mock = 0.8.0
simplejson = 2.2.1
djangorestframework = 2.2.7
markdown = 2.3.1

[django]
recipe = djangorecipe
project = project
settings = production
eggs = ${buildout:eggs}
extra-paths = ${buildout:extra-paths}
wsgi = true
wsgilog = ${buildout:directory}/var/log/wsgi.log

[mkdir]
recipe = z3c.recipe.mkdir
paths =
    ${buildout:directory}/var/htdocs/static
    ${buildout:directory}/var/log

[apacheconf]
recipe = collective.recipe.template
input = ${buildout:directory}/etc/apache.conf.in
output = ${buildout:directory}/etc/apache.conf

[production.py]
recipe = collective.recipe.template
input = ${buildout:directory}/etc/production.py.in
output = ${buildout:directory}/etc/production.py

[my.cnf]
recipe = collective.recipe.template
input = ${buildout:directory}/etc/my.cnf.in
output = ${buildout:directory}/etc/my.cnf

[scribd-patch]
recipe = collective.recipe.patch
path = parts/python-scribd/scribd/
patches = patches/scribd-issue-3.diff

[jquery-ui]
recipe = hexagonit.recipe.download
url = http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/files/jquery-ui-1.8.19.zip
destination = ${buildout:directory}/var/vendor-staticfiles
ignore-existing = true
excludes =
    index.html
    development-bundle/*

[tinymce]
recipe = hexagonit.recipe.download
url = https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/archive/3.4.4.zip
destination = ${buildout:directory}/var/vendor-staticfiles
ignore-existing = true
excludes =
    tinymce/changelog.txt
    examples/*
strip-top-level-dir = true
```

Comment: Are you using a version pin in your `buildout.cfg`? Can you share your `buildout.cfg` configuration?

Comment: @MartijnPieters http://pastebin.com/ggmYskdd here it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buildout loaded the most recent version of `django-debug-toolbar` but that version requires Django 1.4.2 or newer.

You'll need to pin it to an earlier version that still supports Django 1.3. The last version that I can find in the [project repository](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) is [version 0.9.4](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-debug-toolbar/0.9.4).

Pin the package in your `[versions]` section:

```
django-debug-toolbar = 0.9.4
```